# How to control video card in my self-developed OS?

Tags: c, operating-system, driver

I am developing my own OS and for days I’ve been wondering how to control video card, audio card to build a delicate GUI. It seems that the procedure is a bit different from that of controlling mouse or keyboard.

By the way,

1.How does an OS recognize hardware drivers?

2.Are all hardware drivers written for specific platforms (such as Windows,Linux,etc.)?

Still freshman in the university and failed to find relevant information

thanks for help =)

Comment: While this appear too broad to answer, I wish you good luck with the OS development, its not that common among freshmen these days :-)

Comment: See also https://wiki.osdev.org/Category:Drivers

Comment: For the Video drivers I don't think you can create [VESA](https://wiki.osdev.org/VESA_Video_Modes) universal driver. For the audio you can use [AC97](https://wiki.osdev.org/AC97) driver. In any case, my suggestion is join some existing kernel project like Linux, FreeBSD, NetBSD  etc. Operating system is not just a kernel, it is much more then just a kernel.

Comment: advice: don't dig into gpu, if you don't want to be demotivated too soon, just use plain framebuffer for software drawing.

Answer (score 1):

> how to control video card

Graphics cards typically support a VGA mode and the VESA 2.0 standard. So this could be a good starting point for your first video driver.

> 1. How does an OS recognize hardware drivers?

Linux uses a device tree describing the hardware which has a *compatible* field for every item that needs a driver. All hardware drivers are kept in linker generated lists. If a driver has the same *compatible* value it can be used to drive the hardware. The linker list item is generated from a macro in the driver code using a specialized linker script.

> 2. Are all hardware drivers written for specific platforms (such as Windows, Linux, etc.)?

If you provide the right wrappers you may be able to reuse existing drivers. E.g. U-Boot reuses Linux drivers for USB devices. And the [NDISwrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NDISwrapper) can be used to run Windows WLAN drivers on Linux.